# Generating a XSD file from Powerdesigner

Tags: database, xsd, powerdesigner

Is there a simple way to make Powerdesigner generate an XSD file? It generates an XSM file, but it's not the same specification. If there were a simple way of doing it, it would ease my life as heaven :P.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the contents of this XSD file? A DTD definition?

In that case, it's managed as a different XSM "language" by PowerDesigner, so you'd have to change the language (from XML Schema Definition to Document Type Definition) in order to generate a diffferent schema.